# Почему липа - синоним подлога?

Tags: этимология

Не нашла тут подобного вопроса, поэтому хочу спросить. Липой называют что-то поддельное, обман, подлог. А почему, собственно, липа? Чем провинилось дерево?))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Липовый - значит фальшивый (документ). На воровском жаргоне поддельный паспорт назывался : *липовый глаз* (*липовый глазок*), см. ниже цитату. Документы в 19 веке были без фотографий, поэтому слово *глаз* употреблено в переносном смысле. Что может напомнить в документе глаз? Только большая круглая печать, конечно. Она, в свою очередь, называлась **лепухой**. Из чего ее изготовляли умельцы, доподлинно неизвестно, но то, что печать "лепят", "прилепляют" к документам - возражений не вызывает. К тому же ее надо сначала к специальной подушечке с красящим составом плотно прижать, а потом сделать оттиск, печать при этом может слегка прилипать. Вот так, или примерно так возникло жаргонное выражение "липовый глазок".
Версия вполне самодостаточная.
Первые упоминания в литературе (Нацкорпус) нашего сабжа. Все они связаны с криминалом, разумеется.

> В. В. Крестовский. Петербургские трущобы. Книга о сытых и голодных. (1864)
> ― Точно, нужна. Липовый глазок *надобно добыть…* 
>
>  Поддельный паспорт (жарг. ).
>
> В. М. Дорошевич. Сахалин (Каторга) (1903)
> ― Да ведь и он-то настоящий, не липовый.
>
> Валентин Курицын. Томские трущобы (1906)
> ― Вот какое дело, ― продолжал Егорин, когда они остались с Козырем наедине, ― перво-наперво, скажи ты мне, вид у тебя есть. ― Есть «липовый». В Иркутске еще справил.
>
> Л. М. Леонов. Вор. Часть 3 (1927)
> Оно и вправду лихо там все обставлено, при чтении, как от горчицы, глаза пощипывает, только ведь это все врака одна на лирической патоке, чистая липа, как у нас блатные говорят...

Comment: Тоже задалась этим вопросом после того, как узнала о технологии изготовления липового мёда, после чего решала, что это очень правдоподобная версия происхождения значения "липовый" как поддельный, не настоящий.

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, допустимо ли по правилам сайта давать ссылку в качестве ответа, но по-моему, лучше и не объяснишь...

http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/111365-pochemu-poddelku-nazyvajut-lipa.html

Считаю версию про изготовление поддельных печатей из липы достоверной.

Comment: Сслыку  - можно и нужно, особенно если она Вашу версию подтверждает.
Но, во-первых, по Ващей сслыке - несколько версий (все весьма сомнительные), Вы хоть говорите, о какая Вам понравилась.  
А во-вторых, вопрос давно обсуждался
http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/8462/

Comment: Спасибо, поправил. ))

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Answer (score 0):

Λείπω глагол греческого языка, обозначает отсутствую, пропускаю. Вот и вся разгадка.